# Python urlopen taking long time to load web page

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am using following code to open web page

```
cj_civil = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj_civil))
```

Problem is opener.open function taking around 20 sec to load web page . But if I open same site in browser then it loads faster.

What can I do to load web page faster in code? I am also using correct headers values.

Is there any alternative for urllib2 which is faster than urllib2 and also handle cookie automatically?

Comment: If you post where site url I think it will be easier to help you

Comment: Your browser may be caching data. Try to do the same benchmark with cache disabled.

Comment: Hey, I used pycurl module instead of urllib2 and it's quiet fast.
reference ur l for pycurl http://www.angryobjects.com/2011/10/15/http-with-python-pycurl-by-example/

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any alternative for urllib2 which is faster than urllib2 and
> also handle cookie automatically?

Yes there are: [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/), [httpx](https://pypi.org/search/?q=httpx), and others built on top of them ([cloudscraper](https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/) etc).